# Update SQL database with preparedStatement in Java

Tags: java, sql, derby

I have a java app with an SQL database using preparedStatement to insert rows into the database. I want the program to be able to update rows based on the serial number (unique).

```
 Connection conn = null; 
    Statement st = null;
try {
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/db01", "Administrator", "admin"); //run procedure getConnection to connect to the database - see below
     st = conn.createStatement(); //set up a statement st to enable you to send SQL statements to the database.
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(FormTwo1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}


        System.out.println ("Successful Connection");
```

...

```
String query = "insert into TB01(SERIAL,BLADETYPE,STARTT1,AIRT1,FOAMT1,SCT1,FINISHT1) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    try (PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query)) {
        pstmt.setString(1, bladeSerial);
        pstmt.setString(2, itemText);
        pstmt.setString(3, String.valueOf(startTime1));
        pstmt.setString(4, String.valueOf(airTime1));
        pstmt.setString(5, String.valueOf(foamTime1));
        pstmt.setString(6, String.valueOf(scTime1));
        pstmt.setString(7, String.valueOf(finishTime1));
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        // Exception handling
        Logger.getLogger(FormTwo1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Where serial, bladetype are VARCHAR and startT1, foamTime1, scTime1 & finishTime1 are all LocalTime variables (hence the string.valueof for formatting).

The database is db01, the table is TB01

I want the program to insert/update the records dependent on whether the serial number is already in the db.

Comment: What is your question? If you want to update rows you need to use an `UPDATE` statement, not an `INSERT` statement. Also: the way you use it, `TB01` is a _table_ not a "database".

Comment: Sorry, I would like the code to insert an update if it is a unique serial, or update a line in the db if it is already inputted.  You are correct, TB01 is the table & DB01 is the database.

Comment: In Derby you can use a [`MERGE`](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/ref/rrefsqljmerge.html) statement for that. Unrelated, but: you should **never** pass numbers or dates as Strings. **Always** use the appropriate data type. Use `setInt()` for integers, `setDate()`  for dates, `setTimestamp()` for timestamps and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is now working.  Thanks for Prashant for his answer.  Once slightly adapted it worked well

```
String query = ("UPDATE TB01 SET BLADETYPE=?,STARTT1=?,AIRT1=?,FOAMT1=?,SCT1=?,FINISHT1=? WHERE SERIAL=?");
try (PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query)) {
    pstmt.setString(7, bladeSerial);
    pstmt.setString(1, itemText);
    pstmt.setString(2, String.valueOf(startTime1));
    pstmt.setString(3, String.valueOf(airTime1));
    pstmt.setString(4, String.valueOf(foamTime1));
    pstmt.setString(5, String.valueOf(scTime1));
    pstmt.setString(6, String.valueOf(finishTime1));
    pstmt.executeUpdate();
                                                             }
catch (SQLException ex) {
    // Exception handling
    Logger.getLogger(FormTwo1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                          }
```

Note as SERIAL had moved to the end of the string, the order also needed changing on the setString commands.

Answer (score -2):

```
try{
String host="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/databasename";
String user="database_user_name";
String pass="database_password";
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(host,user,pass);
PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement("update table_name set BLADETYPE=?,STARTT1=?,AIRT1=?,FOAMT1=?,SCT1=?,FINISHT1, where SERIAL=?");
 stmt.setString(1, itemText);
 stmt.setString(2, String.valueOf(startTime1));
 stmt.setString(3, String.valueOf(airTime1));
 stmt.setString(4, String.valueOf(foamTime1));
 stmt.setString(5, String.valueOf(scTime1));
 stmt.setString(6, String.valueOf(finishTime1));
 stmt.setString(7, bladeSerial);
 stmt.executeUpdate();
}
catch (SQLException ex) {
Logger.getLogger(FormTwo1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I get an error however with this code at FINISHT1, where SERIAL=?

Comment: I changed it to FINISHT1=? where SERIAL=?... but the code then does not execute

Comment: use string object in double quote "" and also correct your database and table name because in your question you use same name for both that confuse us